# LINQ get list from list by comparing enum

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get a list of objects from a list by comparing an enum that is passed into the method.

```
public List<IAnimal> GetListOfAnimalsByType(IAnimal.AnimalType animalType)
{
    List<IAnimal> animalTypeList = animalList.SelectMany(ani => ani.Type == animaleType);
    if(animalTypeList != null)
    {
        return animalTypeList;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: also, you should reconsider your naming of `IAnimal`, it sounds like an interface but obviously it's not since you can't define a nested type within an interface.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you really just want `Where` instead of `SelectMany`:

```
public List<IAnimal> GetListOfAnimalsByType(IAnimal.AnimalType animalType)
{
    return animalList.Where(ani => ani.Type == animaleType).ToList();
}
```

[`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany) is used to extract one sequence from each element within an original sequence, and usually "flatten" the resulting sequences together... whereas [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.where) is used for filtering.

Additionally:

- The `ToList()` call is necessary because LINQ returns `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`, not `List<T>`
- Your `if` statement is unnecessary as sequence-producing LINQ operators (e.g. `Where`, `Select` etc never return null; they'll return an empty sequence if necessary
- Even if the call *could* return null, you're returning the value of `animalTypeList` in both cases... "if the value is null, return null, otherwise return the value"... so you could still just return the result of the call

Comment: But if he want to return null, he can change condition to animalTypeList.Any(), because this list will never be null.

Comment: @PawełReszka: Then just check if there is any item. Why would you want to return `null` anyway?

Comment: No idea;) I just wanted to point that your function will never return null, but OP in some cases wanted to return null. I just wanted to clear out to OP, that he won't get null.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) to get a list out of the `SelectMany`. Also, a [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) would suffice.

The methods `SelectMany` and `Where` return a `IEnumerable<TSource>`, which isn't a `List<T>` of course. That's why you need to call `ToList`.

```
List<IAnimal> animalTypeList = animalList
                               .Where(ani => ani.Type == animaleType)
                               .ToList();
```